# root password request pop-up every 15 minutes

Tags: 14.10, root, malware

I don't know what application is asking for the root password for every 15 minutes. Is there any way that I can figure it out? I get a screen 'Authentication Required' 'Authentication is required to change your own user data'.

```
PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
25605 ?        Ss     0:00 upstart --user
25687 ?        Ss     0:01 dbus-daemon --fork --session --address=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-pt2NBKK8ZA
25697 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hud/window-stack-bridge
25698 ?        Ss     0:00 upstart-event-bridge
25707 ?        SLl    0:03 gnome-keyring-daemon --start
25708 ?        Sl     0:01 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/bamf/bamfdaemon
25729 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi-bus-launcher
25734 ?        S      0:00 upstart-dbus-bridge --daemon --session --user --bus-name session
25738 ?        S      0:00 upstart-dbus-bridge --daemon --system --user --bus-name system
25740 ?        S      0:00 upstart-file-bridge --daemon --user
25748 ?        S      0:00 /bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/etc/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 3
25757 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session
25761 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
25767 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs -f -o big_writes
25776 ?        Ssl    0:07 /usr/bin/ibus-daemon --daemonize --xim
25792 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-dconf
25793 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-ui-gtk3
25796 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon
25798 ?        Sl     0:01 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-x11 --kill-daemon
25805 ?        Ssl    0:00 gnome-session --session=gnome
25829 ?        Sl     0:01 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-engine-simple
25881 ?        S<l    0:31 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
25918 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-printer
25922 ?        Rl     3:45 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
25961 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-calendar-server
25967 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-source-registry
25972 ?        SLl    0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-online-accounts/goa-daemon
25974 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-metadata
25982 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5
25992 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
25998 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
26003 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory
26005 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
26010 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-goa-volume-monitor
26014 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor
26018 ?        Sl     0:10 nautilus -n
26025 ?        SNl    0:00 /usr/lib/tracker/tracker-extract
26030 ?        SNl    0:00 /usr/lib/tracker/tracker-miner-fs
26033 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/tracker/tracker-store
26069 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-trash --spawner :1.8 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/0
26130 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-burn --spawner :1.8 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/1
26139 ?        Sl     0:34 /home/raza/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-2.10.52/dropbox /newerversion
26237 ?        SLl    1:35 /opt/google/chrome/chrome     
26245 ?        S      0:00 cat
26246 ?        S      0:00 cat
26248 ?        S      0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote --enable-crash-reporter=CD0EA585-317B-437E-CB75-1466EF82B384
26249 ?        S      0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote --enable-crash-reporter=CD0EA585-317B-437E-CB75-1466EF82B384
26253 ?        S      0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox /opt/google/chrome/nacl_helper
26254 ?        S      0:00 /opt/google/chrome/nacl_helper
26256 ?        S      0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote --enable-crash-reporter=CD0EA585-317B-437E-CB75-1466EF82B384
26259 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconf/gconfd-2
26276 ?        Sl     0:54 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=gpu-process --channel=26237.0.2096599178 --enable-crash-reporter=CD0EA585-317B-437E-CB75-1466EF82B384 --supports-dual-gpus=false --gpu-driver-bug-workarounds=1,15,22,34,38 --disable-accelerated-video-decode --gpu-vendor-id=0x1002 --gpu-device-id=0x683d --gpu-driver-vendor=ATI / AMD --gpu-driver-version=14.201.1006.1002 --enable-crash-reporter=CD0EA585-317B-437E-CB75-1466EF82B384
26454 ?        Sl     0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --enable-deferred-image-decoding --lang=en-GB --force-fieldtrials=ChromeSuggestions/Default/DomRel-Enable/enable/EnhancedBookmarks/Default/ExtensionContentVerification/Enforce/ExtensionInstallVerification/None/GCM/Enabled/NewProfileManagement/OldAvatarMenu/OmniboxBundledExperimentV1/StandardR4/PasswordGeneration/Disabled/Prerender/PrerenderControl/QUIC/Disabled/RememberCertificateErrorDecisions/Default/SafeBrowsingIncidentReportingService/Default/SettingsEnforcement/no_enforcement/UMA-Dynamic-Binary-Uniformity-Trial/default/UMA-New-Install-Uniformity-Trial/Experiment/UMA-Population-Restrict/normal/UMA-Session-Randomized-Uniformity-Trial-5-Percent/group_17/UMA-Uniformity-Trial-1-Percent/group_68/UMA-Uniformity-Trial-10-Percent/group_09/UMA-Uniformity-Trial-100-Percent/group_01/UMA-Uniformity-Trial-20-Percent/group_02/UMA-Uniformity-Trial-5-Percent/group_04/UMA-Uniformity-Trial-50-Percent/group_01/VoiceTrigger/Install/ --enable-crash-reporter=CD0EA585-317B-437E-CB75-1466EF82B384 --extension-process --enable-webrtc-hw-h264-encoding --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --enable-delegated-renderer --enable-impl-side-painting --num-raster-threads=1 --disable-accelerated-video-decode --channel=26237.20.486090337
26734 ?        S      0:00 /bin/sh /opt/idea/bin/idea.sh
26934 ?        Sl     0:00 /opt/google/chrome/nacl_helper
27003 ?        Sl     0:00 zeitgeist-datahub
27004 ?        Sl     0:17 /usr/bin/python /opt/extras.ubuntu.com/variety/bin/variety
27009 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/zeitgeist-daemon
27016 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zeitgeist-fts
27018 ?        S      0:00 /bin/cat
27081 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/dconf/dconf-service
27275 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/3.12/evolution-alarm-notify
27344 ?        Sl     0:00 update-notifier
27478 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/deja-dup/deja-dup-monitor
27489 ?        Sl     0:27 spotify
27505 ?        S      0:00 spotify
27506 ?        S      0:00 /opt/spotify/spotify-client/Data/SpotifyHelper --type=zygote --no-sandbox --lang=en-US --locales-dir-path=/opt/spotify/spotify-client/Data/locales --log-severity=disable --resources-dir-path=/opt/spotify/spotify-client/Data
27542 ?        Sl     0:02 /opt/spotify/spotify-client/Data/SpotifyHelper --type=renderer --js-flags=--harmony-proxies --no-sandbox --lang=en-US --lang=en-US --locales-dir-path=/opt/spotify/spotify-client/Data/locales --log-severity=disable --resources-dir-path=/opt/spotify/spotify-client/Data --disable-accelerated-2d-canvas --disable-accelerated-video-decode --channel=27489.1.513915981
27545 ?        Sl     0:00 /opt/spotify/spotify-client/Data/SpotifyHelper --type=renderer --js-flags=--harmony-proxies --no-sandbox --lang=en-US --lang=en-US --locales-dir-path=/opt/spotify/spotify-client/Data/locales --log-severity=disable --resources-dir-path=/opt/spotify/spotify-client/Data --disable-accelerated-2d-canvas --disable-accelerated-video-decode --channel=27489.2.92972771
27548 ?        Sl     0:00 /opt/spotify/spotify-client/Data/SpotifyHelper --type=renderer --js-flags=--harmony-proxies --no-sandbox --lang=en-US --lang=en-US --locales-dir-path=/opt/spotify/spotify-client/Data/locales --log-severity=disable --resources-dir-path=/opt/spotify/spotify-client/Data --disable-accelerated-2d-canvas --disable-accelerated-video-decode --channel=27489.3.1854564320
27566 ?        Sl     0:01 /opt/spotify/spotify-client/Data/SpotifyHelper --type=renderer --js-flags=--harmony-proxies --no-sandbox --lang=en-US --lang=en-US --locales-dir-path=/opt/spotify/spotify-client/Data/locales --log-severity=disable --resources-dir-path=/opt/spotify/spotify-client/Data --disable-accelerated-2d-canvas --disable-accelerated-video-decode --channel=27489.4.1543385018
27584 ?        Sl     0:19 /opt/spotify/spotify-client/Data/SpotifyHelper --type=gpu-process --channel=27489.5.1014988432 --no-sandbox --lang=en-US --locales-dir-path=/opt/spotify/spotify-client/Data/locales --log-severity=disable --resources-dir-path=/opt/spotify/spotify-client/Data --supports-dual-gpus=false --gpu-driver-bug-workarounds=0,19 --gpu-vendor-id=0x1002 --gpu-device-id=0x683d --gpu-driver-vendor=ATI / AMD --gpu-driver-version=14.201.1006.1002 --lang=en-US --locales-dir-path=/opt/spotify/spotify-client/Data/locales --log-severity=disable --resources-dir-path=/opt/spotify/spotify-client/Data
27645 ?        Sl     0:01 gnome-terminal
27651 ?        S      0:00 gnome-pty-helper
27652 pts/5    Ss     0:00 bash
27766 ?        Sl     2:51 /usr/bin/vlc --started-from-file /media/raza/New_Volume/Node/Building AngularJS and Node.js Apps with the MEAN Stack/02. Creating a Walking Skeleton/04. Installing Clientside Dependencies with Bower.mp4
28377 ?        Sl     6:20 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java -Xms128m -Xmx750m -XX:MaxPermSize=350m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=225m -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/opt/idea/bin/idea64.vmoptions -XX:ErrorFile=/home/raza/java_error_in_IDEA_%p.log -Xbootclasspath/a:/opt/idea/bin/../lib/boot.jar -Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea14 -Djb.restart.code=88 com.intellij.idea.Main
28415 ?        S      0:00 /opt/idea/bin/fsnotifier64
28547 pts/2    Ss+    0:00 /bin/bash --login
29740 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/node --debug-brk=47293 --nolazy server.js
29843 pts/5    R+     0:00 ps -x
```

Comment: Can you please update the question with the output of `ps -x`.

Comment: Updated, I had to remove multiple Chrome processes due to the character limit.

Comment: Have you tried entering the password once? Did it appear even after you entered the password? It might be a Chrome process trying to add password to your keyring.

Comment: I still get this pop-up when I don't have Chrome running. If I log into Ubuntu and leave my computer I would get it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `xlsclients -a -l` while the popup is active. `man xlsclients` (which you should read) begins:

```
NAME  
   xlsclients - list client applications running on a display
```